# Why can't I install Analytics on my Blogger blog?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, blogger

I tried it the following ways:

- added the tracking ID in blog settings
- replaced Blogger's Analytics script with the script Analytics provided
- tried that with and without the `b:include google-analytics` Blogger
  tag
- removed the script and used only that `b:include tag`, before `</body>` and before `</head>` too
- tried Universal and normal Analytics profile too

The result was *"tracking not installed"* on Analytics all the time.

Any ideas? How can I make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post this question here too.It might help
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/analytics

Comment: thanks for the link, I found useful information here and the problem is now solved. :) The main thing is that I should have wait 2 or 3 days and ignore the "not installed" text. And for Blogger, classic Analytics is recommended instead of the universal. I inserted the script and left the tracking ID field blank in blog settigs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody has added it and I had find the answer back then, I'm adding it now, for future reference and to mark this question *Answered* as it is.

**Please note** that this answer applies for my situation **in 2013.** Today, years later the issue may not exists or can be solved in other ways.

---

According to my 5-years-old comment:

I think the most important thing is that I **should have waited** 2 or 3 days and ignored the *"not installed"* text.

Also, for Blogger, Classic Analytics tracking was recommended instead of the Universal one. (I had read this recommendation somewhere in 2013, but now in 2018, I can't find the reference.)

I had inserted the Google Analytics script and left the *Tracking ID* field blank in Blogger's settings, then **it started working after a few days.**